# Spinner in Android ActionBar and refresh listview (from Activity to Fragment)

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

I've a question about to add a spinner on ActionBar (MainActivity) and refresh a listview in a Fragment.
Actually, I've designed a SpinnerAdapter but, unfortunately, I call this item in every fragment to populate the spinner.
Instead, I would only one spinner declared on MainActivity and refresh a listview in a fragment based on item selected.

In res/menu/main.xml I have this item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_spinner"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner" />
```

In MainActivity I call every fragment:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position){
        Fragment frgm = new SummaryFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                frgm = new SummaryFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                frgm = new NewJobFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                frgm = new StatisticsFragment();
                break;
        }

        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, frgm)
                .commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mFragmentTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
```

How can I implement the spinner to refresh a listview in other fragment?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: go through this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html would be helpful i think

Comment: Thanks man! but I have an other question: Is this "from fragment to activity"? I'm searching for "from activity to fragment". Resume: I have a spinner in Mainactivity and refresh a listview in a fragment based on item selected. The doc linked is for this? Thanks!!

Comment: Yes,understand the concept